# Syfmony 2.8: You have requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.bundles_metadata"

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, symfony-2.8

I am a newbie to PHP, We are trying to upgrade our old Symfony project from `2.6` to `2.8`.

After executing the below two commands, When I tried to run the app, I am getting the below exception.

```
composer update symfony/symfony 

composer update
```

**Exception:**

> ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 84: You have
> requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.bundles_metadata".

Could anyone help me with this? TIA.

Comment: You can get an idea of what is happening here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21646 Basically there are commands that run after composer does it's thing and for whatever reason the commands are failing.  I'm shocked that composer did not just spew errors.  You could try clearing the cache and maybe even deleting the vendor directory and then installing again.  But who knows what is in your composer.json file and software this old can be tough to update.  Are you planning on moving to a current version of Symfony?

Comment: @Cerad Yes, I am planning to upgrade the app to Symfony 4.4, a maintained version, since we can't directly upgrade the app to 4.4. I am planning to upgrade the app in the below-mentioned order. 

From 2.5 to 2.6 -> From 2.6 to 2.7 -> From 2.7 to 2.8 -> From 2.8 to 3  -> From 3 to 4.

Comment: I tried removing the vendor and cache folder contents and executed the below commands, but they did not help. 

`php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug`

Comment: Looks like you got it working.  4.4 will lose support in Nov 2022.  Might consider setting your target to maybe 5.4 or even 6.x.  I know the official docs suggest upgrading one version at a time but a lots of things have changed and you will end up with problems like this one which are really just waste your time.  You can jump directly to your final version.  Just requires a bit more Symfony expertise.  At a minimum consider creating a new project in your final version and then try loading any third party stuff.  You may find the third party software is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

**The below steps solved my problem in Windows 10**

**Step 1:** Remove the vendor folder and run the below commands

```
composer dump-autoload 

composer install --no-scripts
```

**Step 2**: Remove the folders available under the cache folder

**Step 3:** Remove the **"boostrap.php.cache"** file and recreate the ***"boostrap.php.cache"*** file using the below command

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

**Step 4:** Clear the cache for all the environments and run the app

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod/qa/dev
```